# Does the equation $\tan(x)=y$ have any non-zero rational solution?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, functional-equations, rational-numbers

Trivially $\tan(0)=0$ but it seems this is the "unique" solution of the equation $\tan(x)=y$ on rational numbers. In fact if we try to make $y$ rational we usually use irrational (transcendental) values for $x$, e.g. $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})=1$.

> **Question 1:** Does the equation $\tan(x)=y$ have any non-zero solution such that both $x,y$ are rational numbers? In the other words are there natural numbers $m,n,p,q$ such that $\tan(\frac{m}{n})=\frac{p}{q}$? If yes, is the number of such solutions infinite?
>
> **Question 2:** Does the equation $\tan(x)=y$ have any non-zero solution such that $x$ is an algebraic number and $y$ is rational? If yes, is the number of such solutions infinite?

Comment: It is a consequence of Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem Have a look at corollary 5 here http://planetmath.org/sites/default/files/texpdf/39438.pdf

Comment: @mfl (+1) Thanks for your nice comment.